# MongoDB trigger does not doing anything, even everything is right

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have a problem with mongoDB, im trying to create trigger, that will take server date and compare it with property DueDate and if the DueTime is lesser or equal of the server time, it should swap property borrowed to false.

Problem is that it didnt work and im so lost i tried everything.

There is my trigger function:

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {
    const mongo = context.services.get("MongoDB");
    const now = new Date();
    const booksLended = mongo.db("test").collection("bookslendeds");
    var filter = {DueDate: {$lt: now.toISOString()}, Borrowed: true};
    var update = {$set: {Borrowed: false}};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(filter));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(update));

    return booksLended.updateMany(filter, update);
};
```

This is a console logs:

```
> ran on Wed Jan 18 2023 23:48:10 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
> took 524.689137ms
> logs: 
{"DueDate":{"$lt":"2023-01-18T22:48:11.778Z"},"Borrowed":true}
{"$set":{"Borrowed":false}}
> result: 
{
  "matchedCount": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "modifiedCount": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"matchedCount":{"$numberInt":"0"},"modifiedCount":{"$numberInt":"0"}}')
```

[DataModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF8NH.png)

Comment: try using `{$lt: now}` instead of `{$lt: now.toISOString()}`

Comment: Works, please add this as reply not a comment so i can check that as answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype of the `DueDate` field is probably UTC datetime, while `.toISOString()` is returning a string.  MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive, so these will not match.

Instead, use the date object directly in the query, like:

```
var filter = {DueDate: {$lt: now}, Borrowed: true};
```